# XCUIElementQuery to return elements not containing particular elements

Tags: swift, xcode, xcuitest

As the title suggests, I need to find the better way to get access to elements or cells that don't contain a particular object.

The object is always either there or not. No duplicates within the same element either.

Currently, what I'm doing is matching the main element I need, and checking through its children 1 by 1 until I get what i want.

```
let elements = app.cells.matching(identifier: "someelement").allElementsBoundByIndex 
for element in elements {
    if element.button["somebuttonelement"].exists 
        // do something
}
```